# What does a RewardItem contain?

Tags: android, admob

This is the code to present the user with a `RewardedAd`, an video ad to watch:

```
        rewardedAd.show(this, new OnUserEarnedRewardListener() {
            @Override
            public void onUserEarnedReward(@NonNull RewardItem rewardItem) {

            }
        });
```

So if the user earned a reward, there is a `RewardItem`. This is the [documentation for `RewardItem`](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/ads/rewarded/RewardItem), which frankly doesn't document anything. `RewardItem` offers two methods:

```
abstract int    getAmount()
```

and

```
abstract String     getType()
```

What is the `amount` actually? The percentage of the video watched maybe? And what are the possible values of `type`? I have no idea.

The [documentation for `RewardedAd`](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/ads/rewarded/RewardedAd) has a complete code example. So what do they do with the `RewardItem`? They print it to a `Toast`:

```
       rewardedAd.show(
             this,
             new OnUserEarnedRewardListener() {
                 @Override
                 public void onUserEarnedReward(@NonNull RewardItem rewardItem) {
                     Toast.makeText(
                         MainActivity.this,
                         "onRewarded! currency: "
                             + rewardItem.getType() + "    amount: "
                             + rewardItem.getAmount(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                 }
             });
```

So, what is this? Is `type` an actual currency, like Euros? Is `amount` the money I just made from the user watching the video?

Is there any authoritive documentation for what a `RewardItem` actually is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set reward `type` and `amount` yourself when you create a rewarded ad unit in your Google AdMob. For example when you set it to type `coins` and amount `10`, that's what you should receive in the callback. Think default is type `""` and amount `1`.

See documentation for creating an rewarded ad unit, step 8: https://support.google.com/admob/answer/7311747?hl=en

Answer (score -2):

The RewardItem typically refers to a unit of virtual currency or in-app item that a user can earn or receive as a reward in a mobile or online game or application. The specific content and properties of a RewardItem can vary widely depending on the game or app's design and the rewards system in place. However, a RewardItem commonly contains the following information:

**1. Name/Title:**

A name or title that describes the reward, such as "Gold Coins," "Gems," "Power-ups," or any other virtual currency or in-game item.

**2.Quantity:** The number of units of the reward item that the user receives. For example, "5 Gold Coins" or "2 Power-ups."

**3. Value/Points:** In some cases, a reward item may have a point value or score associated with it. This can be used in games to determine a player's score or ranking.

**4. Image/Icon:** A visual representation of the reward item, often displayed as an icon or image to make it visually identifiable to the user.

**5. Description:** A brief description or tooltip that provides more information about the reward item, its usage, or its significance in the game.

**6. Category/Type:** Some games or apps categorize their reward items. For instance, rewards might be classified as "Currency," "Boosts," "Cosmetics," etc.

**7. Usage:** Information on how the reward item can be used within the game or app. For example, it might be used to purchase in-game items, unlock features, or progress through the game.

**8. Expiration:** In certain cases, reward items may have an expiration date, after which they become invalid if not used.